# Refactor int to array, safely

Tags: c++, refactoring

Disclaimer: I'm unsure if this questions fits this forum, but it might.

Preamble: This question is about a project in C++98 and has mixed C and C++ sources. It also has global variables, and a lot of bad code.

I have a large code base (an old one) with an `int theVar[]` variable which represents a property of an object which is a collection. The model used to have only one instance of "the object". A new requirement came along which called for having more than one instance of the object, so I had to refactor this `int[]` into an `int[][]`, where the first index specified the instance of the object. Changing the type of the variable in the declaration allows the compiler to warn me of places in the code in need of updating, but it misses things such as:

`if (theVar[i]) ...`

And more.

How can I perform this refactoring in the safest way?

**NOTE**

There is some really good advice in the comments, I appreciate it, this question might not have a best answer, but the comments have given me some good directions to follow.

Comment: Write a little wrapper container that only supports `.at()`, not subscript operator, then swap it out for a `std::vector` when you are done?

Comment: This is a C++98 program... and it's mixed c and c++...

Comment: Oh man, that should be up front and center in the question!

Comment: You can rename the variable then go through each case manually where compilation fails, then rename it back depending on how you used it

Comment: Rename it to theVarArray. Then all the uses are errors. If you still want it to be called theVar, then rename it back after you find all the uses.

Comment: Is this `theVar` used to handle some `C` callback (this happens when bad `C` API design makes it hard to bridge callback to instance of some `C++` class)? If this is the issue (or something similar) you should start from explaining connection between `C` and `C++` API you have problem with.

Comment: regex search through usage to find cases when the 2nd `[]` is missing